# Executing application with full path gives syntax error

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "./resend-emails.lock" ]; then
        echo "waiting";
else
        touch "./resend-emails.lock";
        /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node ./resend-emails.sh;
        #node ./resend-emails.sh;
        unlink "./resend-emails.lock";
fi
```

The line /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node ./resend-emails.sh; makes the whole script return the error

if

```
 [ -f "./resend-emails.lock" ]; then
   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

But if I replace it with the one that is commented below it works just fine. How can I use the full path to execute node?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to execute a bash script with a python interpreter.

Comment: @glennjackman just out of curiosity I executed using python and the error happens on line 1 on the second double quote

Comment: If something goes wrong in bash, you won't see the word "SyntaxError". How exactly do you invoke this script?

Comment: Oh, I see now, you're running the script with `node` -- use `bash script.sh`

Comment: Wait, what should this line do: `/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node ./resend-emails.sh` -- did you intend to invoke a `*.js` file with node?

Comment: holy dang it was a typo, it should be executing resend-emails.js; mah bad, thank you for the help

Comment: Better is not to specify an explicit interpreter at all. Let the program you're running decide if it should be executed with `bash` or `node` by invoking that script directly. (If you do that _and also_ drop the `.sh` or `.js` extensions, that'll let yet you rewrite your scripts in different languages without needing to change anything but the one executable you rewrote! Moreover, `.sh` is a bad choice for bash scripts -- bash is not `sh`; bash and POSIX sh are two distinct languages, and not all bash code can be run by `sh`)